# "Viewport" by META tag in HTML ... if iPad = X and if iPhone = Y?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, ipad, meta-tags

Working good with iPad but not iPhone

Any code can I direction to iPad and iPhone

for iPad

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1040px, minimum-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

for iPhone

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=440px, minimum-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: im done with

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1040px, minimum-scale=0.1, maximum-scale=1.0" />

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iPhone max-width is 480px not 440px

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no, width=device-width"/>

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
```

This sets the viewpoint with the scaleable option off

```
<link media="only screen and (device-width: 768px)" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ipad.css" type="text/css" title="no title"/>
```

This is a css file for only iPad

```
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" rel="stylesheet" href="css/small-device.css" type="text/css" title="no title"/>
```

This is a css file for only iPhone

They are conditional comments so they will only apply to specific devices with specified max-widths.

Comment: This answer makes no sense at all :/