# Javascript ios unzoom trigger

Tags: jquery, ios, safari, web, pinchzoom

I want to be able to have a bit of **js or jQuery** that takes a zoomed in ('pinched') screen safari ios website:

[image]

and makes it un-zoom:

[image]

Let me know if you have an idea or even a lead!

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide the minimum-scale and maximum-scale.  See this SO post for more examples: ["Viewport" by META tag in HTML ... if iPad = X and if iPhone = Y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135703/viewport-by-meta-tag-in-html-if-ipad-x-and-if-iphone-y)

Comment: Agreed - and I have already done this. What I am asking for though is not what you have described: a line of jQuery/js that takes a pinched screen and 'unpinches' it.

Comment: Did you see this SO post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249364/how-do-you-change-zoom-level-dynamically-with-javascript  Maybe it's not possible?  Can you explain what you are trying to do with the page? Maybe there is a different way

Comment: Yes - again it's not as requested :(

Comment: If nobody has gotten back now it might be impossible